# Why does setting color on a material with hex string and THREE.Color object produces different results?

Tags: colors, three.js, react-three-fiber

When I set the color on the material as a Hex String, the mesh is rendered with a color close to what I expect. But when I set it with an instance of `THREE.Color(sameHexString)`, the mesh has a different color.

I have a simplified code that reproduces this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wind-qhp99?file=/src/App.js

With `linear` on the `<Canvas>` both meshes are rendered with same color, but a different color than the previous 2.

Comment: Seems similar to your issue: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-color-problem/28920

Answer (score 0):

The link to the [discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-color-problem/28920) that @prisoner849 commented described the exact problem. Thanks @prisoner849.

Converting the Color instance solved this problem. For more details follow the [discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-color-problem/28920).

```
new THREE.Color(hexString).convertSRGBToLinear()
```